# strip() command stripping too much

Tags: python

I need to get at the instance ID of an AWS server using strip. I create an ec2 server with the `create_instances()` command which returns a list:

```
    instance = ec2_resource.create_instances(
        ImageId=image_id,
        MinCount=1,
        MaxCount=max_count,
        InstanceType=instance_type,
        KeyName=key_name,
        SubnetId=subnet_id
     print(instances)
```

Gives me this:
`[ec2.Instance(id='i-0ee74643266b26fca')]`

I'm trying to use only the instance ID (between the quotes). I'm trying to strip it like this:

```
instance_id = str(instance).strip('[ec2.Instance(id=\'\')]')
print(f"Instance ID: {instance_id}")
```

However what I get back is this:

```
Instance ID: -0ee74643266b26f
```

It strips off the `i` at the beginning of `i-0ee74643266b26fca`.

I can't use the result in future calls because it's missing the `i`. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: `strip` treats its argument as an iterable of characters subject to removal, not a single prefix/suffix.

Comment: ok. so it's removing the `i` at the beginning of the instance id because it sees `id` in  `instance_id`. Right? How can I get it to remove just the `id` and not the `i` in the instance id?

Comment: *"I need to get at the instance ID of an AWS server using strip."* I believe that you need to get the instance ID of an AWS server, and there is no particular reason you must do it using `strip`, unless this is some kind of abstract challenge with that requirement.

Comment: using Google `"ec2_resource.create_instances get ID"` I found that you can get it using `instance[0].instance_id` or maybe even `instance.instance_id` and you don't have to convert it to string. See [aws boto - how to create instance and return instance_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028223/aws-boto-how-to-create-instance-and-return-instance-id)

Comment: if you really have to use string then slice it - ie. `[18:-3] ` gives what you need - `"[ec2.Instance(id='i-0ee74643266b26fca')]"[18:-3]`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can access `id` as it is an attribute without the need of any string manipulation

Comment: @furas thank you! That works perfectly. You should put it as an answer so I can accept it. I used `instance_id = instance[0].instance_id` to get the instance id.

Comment: @bluethundr I already put this as answer 20 minut ago :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can get it directly - without converting to string

```
instance[0].instance_id
```

See [aws boto - how to create instance and return instance_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028223/aws-boto-how-to-create-instance-and-return-instance-id)

It seems it can create many instances so you may need `for`-loop to get all IDs

```
for item in instance:
    print(item.instance_id)
```

or

```
all_ids = [item.instance_id for for item in instance]
```

Answer (score 3):

`strip` treats is argument not as a prefix/suffix to remove, but as a iterable containing the individual characters that are subject to removal. Any prefix or suffix consisting entirely of characters from the argument
will be stripped, regardless of order.

```
>>> "fofofofofo".strip("of")
""
```

Rather than strip the surrounding characters, use a regular expression to *extract* the id.

```
import re


if (m := re.search("id='(.*)'", s)) is not None:
    instance_id = m.group(1)
```

or, pre-Python 3.8,

```
m = re.search("id='(.*)'", s)
if m is not None:
    instance_id = m.group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `split` rather than `strip`

```
"[ec2.Instance(id='i-0ee74643266b26fca')]".split("'")
#Makes a list
['[ec2.Instance(id=', 'i-0ee74643266b26fca', ')]']

"[ec2.Instance(id='i-0ee74643266b26fca')]".split("'")[1]
#Get the item at position [1] from the list
'i-0ee74643266b26fca'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of strip you can use

```
instance_id = (str(instance).split('\''))[1]
```

Note - When you are using ' in strings you have to use escape sequence \' 
in split rather than split(''') you have to use split('\'')